# Accessing Binance with API from two devices at once

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I have tried googling this and cant find much information on it.

I simply just want to know, are there any drawbacks to accessing binance via API from two devices?

Specifically my situation is that I have a trading bot on a VPS that runs 24/7. while it is running, I would like to work on updates on my computer which entails accessing the account and fetching market data.

Will this interfere with my trade bot in any way?

Comment: You don't need real APIs to fetch market data. You only need them for working with account data. Try getting kline data with a client setup with api1 & api2 set to "aaa" and "bbb", it should still work.

Comment: ah, nice! thank you

Comment: I suppose I should clarify for anyone that's a bit confused - by api1 and api2 I'm talking about the keys. [Of course you need a real API to fetch market data - but you don't need real private keys for many functions of that API]

Comment: working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Binance API keys do not have an IP address or session limitations unless you impose them yourself in the settings.

Also this is more of a question for Binance customer support, as Binance is private venture and they can decide how you can use your API or not.